# Given line $g$ is parallel to line $h$, how to show that the quadrilateral $PQRS$ is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

how to show that the quadrilateral $PQRS$ is a parallelogram if Q is the composition of two reflections $M_g.M_h(P)=Q$ and $M_g.M_h(S)=R$, providing that both $P$ and $S$ are not in $g$ and $h$.

I know that to show a quadrilateral is a parallelogram, one must show each of the opposite side parallel. However, I am stuck in showing $PS$ is parallel to $QR$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You are basically reflecting line PS first over line g then line h. The isosceles trapezoids $SS_1P_1P$ and $RS_1P_!Q$ have the same angles hence PS is parallel to QR, and RS is parallel to QP both being perpendicular to h and g.